# how to combine two write_dynamic_frame.from_options into one transaction?

Tags: pyspark, transactions, aws-glue

I am using Glue and pyspark. I am writing to two tables like this:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(df1, glueContext, "df1"),
            connection_type="custom.spark",
            connection_options=combinedConf
        )
        

        glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(df2, glueContext, "df2"),
            connection_type="custom.spark",
            connection_options=combinedConf
        )
```

I want to combine them both in one transaction so either both writes to two tables will be written or both will not be written. I thought about `Transactions`, but how can I pass `transaction id` to the `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options` function, I checked the docs but didn't find it.

any idea how to force these two lines to be executed together or not executed at all? Thanks

edit:
I added it this way, but got

```
TypeError: from_options() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transactionId'
```

tx_id = context.start_transaction(read_only=False)
context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(df1, gluecontext, "df1"),
connection_type="custom.spark",
connection_options=config1,
transactionId=tx_id
)

```
context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(df2, gluecontext, "df2"),
connection_type="custom.spark",
connection_options=config2,
transactionId=tx_id
)
    



try:
    
    context.commit_transaction(tx_id)
    print("done writing after transaction")
except Exception:
    context.cancel_transaction(tx_id)
    print("cancel trans")
    raise Exception("the transaction cancelled")
```

Answer (score -1):

Add transactionId in additional_options